# SpriteKit: An efficient way to list large textures as thumbnails

Tags: ios, sprite-kit

I have ~100s of large images (equal to the device background size) that need to be listed in a categorized scroll panel as thumbnails. Around ten images at a time. When clicking on one of the available categories, the scroll panel updates the image list using the image textures in that category. When clicking on one of those images, the full-sized image is displayed in a workspace beside the scroll panel.

The current approach I implemented is loading the original sized textures and scale them down for the thumbnails size. When one of them receives touch event it copies itself (the sprite node with the full-sized texture) to the workspace with re-scaling. The problem is that the list takes a noticeable time to get loaded when clicking on the category buttons. What is the best way to come over this? I'm thinking of building a cache folder with all of the images scaled down to the thumbnail size the first time the app is launched and then use them instead of the original sized textures, but that doesn't feel like the best way to do it. Is there a better way to implement this?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you using a Texture Atlas?

Comment: No. Since they all have the maximum size that the atlas allows (2048 * 2048), it won't make a difference. Add to this that Xcode shows errors when so.

Comment: That kinda leaves you with few options. I think your closing thoughts are worth a try. Have separate thumbnails, put them into a texture atlas and load up the full size image when the thumbnail is touched. You made no mention of what kind of image compression you use for the original size images. It goes without saying that the smaller your image, the faster the load time.

Comment: That needs to be made manually, right? I mean, there is no way to generate the atlas while the app is running. I was thinking of this as a last option. Images are in png formats. Any special suggestion on this?

Comment: The compression all depends on what you can live with in regards to image quality so I cannot comment on that. I remember there are various PNG formats you can use - PNG 8, 24 & 32. Creating a texture atlas on the fly with your large images will have the lag times you are not happy about. Best option would be to already have a texture atlas created as part of your app. There is a great program called TexturePacker to create a texture atlas for you. Take a look at it. http://www.codeandweb.com/texturepacker

Comment: the easiest and arguably best solution is to simply add the thumbnail images to your bundle (project). If you also allow downloading images, have a list of thumbnails on your webserver. Any on-device processing will amount to a less optimal user experience.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your description, I think the best option would be to have a texture atlas for these thumbnail images. Loading the images and generating the thumbnails on the fly takes time as you have discovered.